# ApolloError: variable x is declared as '[String!]!', but used where '_text' is expected

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, hasura

ApolloError: variable 'wallet_addresses' is declared as '[String!]!', but used where '_text' is expected

I get that error above. And my query is below.

````
mutation updateUser(
        $id: Int
        $email: String
        $wallet_addresses: [String!]!
    ) {
        update_dev_user(
          where: {email: {_eq: $email}}
          _set: {
            wallet_addresses: $wallet_addresses
          }
    ){
        returning {
            id
            email
          }
        }
    }```

I believe the mistake is at the `$wallet_addresses: [String!]!` this part. I have no idea how I an define an array type in the parameter.

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZcz9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZcz9.png)

I tried 

[String!]! 
[String!]
[String]
[]

types but got errors in anyway and could find in the docs ( hasura ). I just want to send string array to a table column which has Text[] type.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with giving type _text to wallet_addresses parameter and converted string array to array literal.

doc: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/mutations/postgres/insert/#insert-an-object-with-an-array-field

```
const toArrayLiteral = (arr: string[]) =>
      JSON.stringify(arr)?.replace('[', '{')?.replace(']', '}')?.replaceAll('"', '');
```